# Define ASP.NET MVC route with slashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In a URL like `http://mysite.com/controller/action/123/name-of-article`, is there a way to define the route so that the '123/name-of-article' part is passed in as a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make a wildcard route:

```
MapRoute("{controller}/{action}/{*id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your requirements are, but are you sure you want to pass the name of the article to the controller? Would you be better off just passing the ID then doing a SELECT from the database to get the Name?

If you still wanted to have a URL like `http://mysite.com/controller/action/123/name-of-article`
but only pass in the ID you can use a route like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               "MyNewRoute",            // Route name
               "articles/edit/{id}/{name}",       // URL
               new { controller = "Articles", action = "Edit", id = "" }, // Defaults
               new[] { "YourApp.UI.Controllers" }                       // Namespaces
             );
```

Then your controller action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

}
```